# Meaning of inequality

Tags: inequality, notation

I have the following inequality listed in a textbook $-1 \le x = y \le 1$. What area is this describing and what does the equal sign between the x and y indicate?

Thank you.

Comment: Seems like $x$ is equal to $y$ and $x, y \in [-1, 1]$

Comment: in 3D it's a kind of plane straight road, in 2D a segment

Answer (score 1):

This basically means that $x$ is equal to $y$ and that they are both $-1\geq$ and less than or equal to $1.$